# Retrieving string-encoded binary data from MongoDB in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, binary

I have stored some binary data in MongoDB as a string. How can I retrieve it from PHP?

[This article](http://api.mongodb.org/perl/current/MongoDB/DataTypes.html#Binary%20Data) describes how to do it in Perl, but how can I manage it in PHP?

The following doesn't work:

```
$query = array('md5' => "00<ΧTcwdrC");
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
```

Comment: You link perl docs but you use PHP?

Comment: I need this method in PHP, but i dont find it

Comment: What is the binary data? Loading back binary data in another language should be fine, but why are you using it in query criteria?

Comment: Can you show us an example document this query should find?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentaion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongobindata.tostring.php):

> To access the contents of a MongoBinData, use the bin field.

```
$obj['fieldname']->bin
```